# Doctrine 2: how to auto-get data of related tables?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I got these models like this:

```
class Address{
   /** @id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue**/
   public $id;
   /**  @name @Column(type="string")**/
   public $name;
}
class User{
   /** @id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue**/
   public $id;
   /**
   * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Address")
   * @JoinColumn(name="id_address", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
   public $address
}
```

And schema on MySql:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
address_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Address (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE User ADD FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES Address(id);
```

When i tried to get data from mySql with these code:

```
    $this->model = new stdclass;
    $this->model->address = new AddressModel(); 
    $this->model->user = new UserModel();
    $adr=$this->model->address->getItem(1);
    $user=$this->model->user->getItem(1);
    var_dump($user);exit();
```

In the result, i got all value of user (include its address's value).
When i commented  `$adr=$this->model->address->getAll();`

I would get error:

```
 Warning: require(C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\__CG__Address.php)
```

I realized that Doctrine only mapping when i loaded all data in need.

Here is my question:
How to make doctrine auto-get data from its relationship tables with only a query??? I really don't want to use query builder at all.

Please and thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well you need fetch method `EAGER`

```
/**
* @OneToOne(targetEntity="Address")
* @JoinColumn(name="id_address", referencedColumnName="id", fetch="EAGER")
*/
   public $address
```

This way every time you ask for a `User` you'll retrieve the `Address` entity

Comment: yes this's it. I want to this once.That's y i love progarmming. As if  we were pirate looking for a treasure. Thanks alot.

Comment: could i update `address` of `User` object with only `id` of  `address` entity??

Comment: yes you can, but you need to keep the property (idUser) and the entity user relationship in your entity with all getters an setters. Check for possible side effects when you update your entity through relationship or through id.

Comment: could u tell me more details about 'the entity user relationship in your entity with all getters an setters'. I Know setters and getters. But i can't image about  'the entity user relationship in your entity'. Did u mean the property to  fetch the  data from association talbe `public $address`???

Comment: If what you want is being able to update your entity through the idAddress you just keep both a property `$idAddress` and your property `$address`. `$IdAddress` is a simple  `@ORM\Column(name="id_address")`

Comment: Could i asked u about this problem again? I got  Order model, which is fetching data  of its customer. But The customer's also fetching location data. So i got  error **Warning: require(C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\__CG__Location.php)**. I don't know how to fix. Did i use too much fetch???

Comment: I am reading document of ArrayCollection( Doctrine 2) in hope a way for replace fetch. but still have no way. Could u please give me an advice again?

Comment: you should post a new question for this one

Comment: yeah. I didt it. Thank for helping me alot.